# Matlab: Trace a CLOSED curve

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have an image containing a closed curve. [image]
I want to trace any closed curved in a counter-clockwise way. I found that I may use `bwtraceboundary` function but I don't know how to use it correctly.

Currently my code is:

```
function [] = project()
close all;

origImg = imread('closed.png');
BW = im2bw(imcomplement(rgb2gray(origImg)));
imshow(BW,[]);
s = size(BW);
for row = 2:15:s(1)
    for col = 1:s(2)
        if BW(row,col)
            break;
        end
    end
    contour = bwtraceboundary(BW,[row col],'W',8,1000,'counterclockwise');

    if(~isempty(contour))
        hold on;
        plot(contour(:,2),contour(:,1),'g','LineWidth',2);
        hold on;
        plot(col,row,'gx','LineWidth',2);
    else
        hold on;
        plot(col,row,'rx','LineWidth',2);
end
```

end

Currently my code does not trace the "closed" region!

Any idea how to continue?

Comment: Hm. You may want to thin the image, build a graph and look for an [Eulerian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path). After you have found that, you will want to do a check on all vertices with edge degree of 4 and check for second differentiability of the curve, possibly swapping some edges.

Answer (score 0):

I took you code and commented it, so you know whats goin on.

you got that code from the example of matlab and it does not do what you think it does. You dont need all iterations and you may want to modify the code to get more points of the traced contour. As I don't want to write the code for you I thougth it was a good Idea to explain you what you are doing, so here it is. you can copy paste it and should work, and you should see some kind of animation going on.

Code:

```
% READ IMAGE
origImg = imread('so.png');

% Create a binary image of the original image being white the contours and
% black the rest
BW = im2bw(imcomplement(rgb2gray(origImg)));
% show it
imshow(BW,[]);
% wait 2 seconds so you can see it
pause(2)
s = size(BW);


% Go iterating thougth rows and cols until you find something white
% (contour)
for row = 2:15:s(1)
    for col = 1:s(2)
        if BW(row,col)
            break; %something white found!
        end
    end
    % Trace that boundary! Starting in the white point (row,col) 
    contour = bwtraceboundary(BW,[row col],'W',8,200,'counterclockwise');

    % Did we actually found a contour or its just empty (e.g. it was
    % point)
    if(~isempty(contour))
        % There is a contour! lets plot it (we will only get a piece of it,
        % because we specified that only 200 points of it will be used!

        hold on;
        % plot the contour in green
        plot(contour(:,2),contour(:,1),'g','LineWidth',2);
        hold on;
        % plot the initial point of the conotur in blue
        plot(col,row,'bx','LineWidth',2);
        pause(1)
    else
        % If there was not a contour just put a red X on it
        hold on;
        plot(col,row,'rx','LineWidth',2);
    end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So, is there a way to trace all the closed curve including the inner one?

Comment: @zinon Thats a quite different question and a way more complicated one. I am guessing that what you want is your code to be able to follow the "blue line" in the original image,including the inner loop. That's definetly not straigtforward, and may need complex algorithms, if it can be done.  Try finding the skelleton of the image and things like that. you may want to open a new question showing how you can trace the outer circle but not the inner, and ask for help.

Comment: Yes, I want to follow the direction of the "blue" line.